# How to ensure an application is running on my companie's LAN only and not from outside

Tags: java, security, lan

How to ensure a standalone application is running on my companie's LAN only and not from outside.

The applicaiton is written in java. I want that applicaiton to run only on the local LAN and not outside the company network. When some one tries to run the applicaiton outside the network, the applicaiton should stop.

Comment: One way would be to host a server on your company's LAN and have your application try to connect to it. If it fails, you're not on the LAN and you can call `System.exit` or some equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do that with application. You can do that simply iptables rules. For instance.

Let say, companie's client who have an access to that application are using 10.0.0.0/24 subnet. So you can use following iptables rule to make restriction.

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/255.255.255.0 -i em1 -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```